# map column according to nested dictionary accorging to second column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace, apply

Using vectorization, I want to remap a column according to a nested dictionary depending on the value of a second column. In iteration logic, I would go through the rows; depending on the value in the second column, I would choose an entry from the dictionary's first level (which is a dictionary again) according to which the values are mapped.

**MWE**

I have a data frame with two columns of interest: `country` and `variable`:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"country": ["AA", "BB", "AA", "AA", "BB", "AA"],
                "variable": ["foo/tball", "palace", "bla", "car", "bla", "dog"]})
```

I further have a nested dictionary `dct` (values in `variable` are only unique in combination with the `country`, and I thus cannot unnest the dictionary). `dct` contains strings of entries in `df['variable']` and substrings thereof:

```
dct = {"AA": {'foo': 'NEWFOO', # substring of 'foo/tball'
          'bla' : 'NEWBLA', 
          'cart': 'this value is not in the dataframe'}, # sic! -- not substring of any entry
       "BB": {'pal': 'NEWPAL', # substring of palace
          'bla': 'DIFFERENT_NEWBLA'},
       "CC": {"this": "'CC' dictionary can be ignored"}}
```

I now want to map the entry of `df['variable']` according to `dct[df['country']]` following these rules:

- if the string matches or if the dictionary key is a substring of the entry in `df['variable']` (e.g. `'foo'` in `dct['AA']`: replace the entry according to the dictionary
- otherwise (i.e. if the cell entry is **not** in the dictionary (e.g. `'dog'`), replace with some predefined value (here, `_some_flag_value_`)
- ignore entries in the dictionary that do not match either on the `'country'` column (e.g. `dct["CC"]`) or the `'variable'` column (e.g. `'cart'` in `dct['AA']`).

The desired output should look like this:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({"country": ["AA", "BB", "AA", "AA", "BB", "AA"],
                    "variable": ["NEWFOO", "NEWPAL", "NEWBLA", "_some_flag_value_", 
                                 "DIFFERENT_NEWBLA", "_some_flag_value_"]})
```

I have tried using `df.mapapply()` with several combinations of `lambda` to no avail - can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.cat` to join both the columns with custom separator then use `pd.Series.map`

```
def f(x):
    c, v = x.split('-')
    d = dct.get(c)
    for k,val in d.items():
        if k in v:
           return val
    else:
        return '_some_flag_value_'

df.assign(variable = df['country'].str.cat(df['variable'],sep='-').map(f))

  country           variable
0      AA             NEWFOO
1      BB             NEWPAL
2      AA             NEWBLA
3      AA  _some_flag_value_
4      BB   DIFFERENT_NEWBLA
5      AA  _some_flag_value_
```

Or using `df.apply`<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>

```
def f(x):
    c, v = x
    d = dct.get(c)
    for k,val in d.items():
        if k in v:
           return val
    else:
        return '_some_flag_value_'

df.assign(variable = df.apply(f,axis=1))
```

Timeit results:

Benchmarked using the dataframe given in the question.

```
In [84]: %timeit df.assign(variable = df['country'].str.cat(df['variable'],sep='-').map(f))
    ...:
694 µs ± 22.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [82]: %timeit df.assign(variable = df.apply(f,axis=1))
    ...:
915 µs ± 40.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

<sup><sup>1 `df.apply` over axis is generally avoided as it's slow and for-loops under the hood. Take a look at this [answer by cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)</sup></sup>

Comment: thanks, this looks promising; what king of object is the input `x` to `f` if using apply? This is unpacked but I don't understand what we're passing in there. The `pd.Series` of `df`?!

Comment: `pd.Series.map` applies the function `f` on each value of the series. So, `df['country'].str.cat(df['variable'],sep='-').map(f)` applies function on each value which is a string. @Ivo

Comment: `df.apply` over axis 1 applies function `f` on each of the row values i.e function `f` is applied on `('AA', 'foo/tball')` and similarly for each row.